# How does UEFI firmware decide which gpt to use for execution control transfer when there are multiple hard drives?

Tags: uefi, firmware

So imagine I have 2 HDDs, how does UEFI firmware decide what drive to boot from? Let's say the two drives have GPT tables on them in the very beginning of their address space?

Comment: Too broad to explain. In short, NVRAM stores that path of the EFI FAT partition.

Comment: Bit more specifically it uses the GUID AKA partUUID to know which ESP to find boot files. Entries can use different ESP. You can see details:`sudo efibootmgr -v` and `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"` to see which entry uses which ESP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition & details: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface